# Oracle Rest Data Service Order by desc nulls last not working

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am not able order by field_name DESC with null last option. Since the default behaviour on DESC is nulls first, I would like them to be pushed at last.

> "$orderby": {"ENAME":"DESC NULLS LAST"}

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

How about such a *trick*? If `ENAME` is NULL, use `CHR(ASCII(1E4))` - something that is, hopefully, far enough to avoid valid first characters in actual names in your database.

```
SQL> with test (id, ename) as
  2    (select 1, 'Little' from dual union
  3     select 2, null     from dual union
  4     select 3, 'Zoot'   from dual
  5    )
  6  select *
  7  from test
  8  order by decode(ename, null, chr(ascii(1E4)), ename) desc;

        ID ENAME
---------- ------
         2
         3 Zoot
         1 Little

SQL>
```